# (python) do I use os.path.join on tar.gz files

Tags: python, tar, compression

I have a tar.gz file, and I want to extract a certain directory but not the whole thing, so I use `TarFile.getmember('foo/bar')`. what I want to know is if I really should be using `TarFile.getmember(os.path.join('foo','bar'))`.

edit:
I'm also wondering if I would use os.path.join for any other function within the tarfile module or zipfile moduple.

Comment: I would imagine that tar files follow the Unix standard for paths, rather than the OS they are being used on, so I think using ``/`` manually might be the better call here - but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the argument to `getmember` is the key inside the tar file, not a local file system path.  Use the slashes.